# query_posts and sub pages?

Tags: query-posts, loop

I have a Page layout like this

```
Parent Page
- Sub page 1
-- sub sub 1
-- sub sub 2
-- sub sub 4
- Sub page 2
-- sub sub 1
-- sub sub 2
-- sub sub 4
```

I want to query every single child page, regardless of how deep I go. This is my query but it only returns direct children(sub page 1 and 2)

```
query_posts('post_type=page&order=ASC&orderby=menu_order&depth=4&post_parent='.$post->ID);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The inner posts don't have a parent of $post->ID but instead on subpages you need to query again using that $post->ID as the parent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can use `get_pages` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) function to solve this. It has `child_of` parameter which does exactly what you wanted.

The only problem is that it returns posts and not set `$wp_query`, so you can't use it as loop, but you can always call `setup_postdata` and then use template tags as in normal posts loop.

```
<?php
    $mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => <PARENT_PAGE_ID>) );
    foreach( $mypages as $page ):
?>
        <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo apply_filters('the_title', $page->post_title); ?></a></h2>
        <div class="entry"><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $page->post_content ); ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
function wpse33151_getSubpages() {      
    global $post;

    $parents = get_post_ancestors($post->post_id);
    krsort($parents);
    $parents = array_merge(array(), $parents);

    if (is_home() || is_single()) {
        $id = get_option('page_for_posts');
        $parent = get_post_ancestors($id);
        $id = $parent[0];
    } elseif($parents) {
        $id = $parents[0];
    } else {
        $id = $post->ID;
    }

    $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of=' . $id . '&echo=0');
    $out = null;

    if ($children) {
        $out = '';
        $out .= '' . get_the_title($id) . '';
        $out .= '';
        $out .= $children;
        $out .= '';
        $out .= '';
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Comment: From which source did you paste this? `$parents = array_merge(array(), $parents);` is merging an array with an empty array. For what reason? Also: `$out .= '' . get_the_title($id) . '';` places a function between 2 times nothing :)